# D3 - Donut charts of multiple sizes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get different donut charts of different sizes.  For example, have a large ring in the center of the collection of donuts.

My code:

```
const arc = d3.arc()
.innerRadius(52.5)
.outerRadius(65)
.startAngle(0);
```

This only sets one size.

[My codepen link](https://codepen.io/stevechezcp5/pen/xJoWMp).

Comment: Welcome! Instead of a const, couldn't you make d3.arc variables of different sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Change the inner and outer radius

You can create a function for example:

```
function create_arc(inner, outer, start){
    start = start || 0;
    var res = d3.arc()
                .innerRadius(inner)
                .outerRadius(outer)
                .startAngle(start);
    return res;
}
```

And you use it like this (according to your code):

```
svg.append("path")
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .attr("d", create_arc(80,100,0)({endAngle: twoPi}));
```

You can even put the inner and outer value in the json